# Passenger+Nginx+Docker app setup

Tags: nginx, docker, passenger, dockerfile, phusion

TL;DR = Cannot get Passenger/Nginx to call our application from Django. "passenger-status" does not show proper Application Group that is shown in our currently live non-Docker server.

Trying to convert a live and running Passenger+Nginx+Django system to a Docker image. We started with the base Phusion:passenger-docker image and now trying to get it running like our live system. We followed the guide [[*here*]](https://github.com/phusion/passenger-docker#nginx_passenger) but when we run the container, Passenger and Nginx do not run our application. Passenger provides the following output:

```
root@e8da5a56faec:/# passenger-status
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648
Version : 5.1.2
Date    : 2017-04-25 01:59:00 +0000
Instance: wXh9AKCm (nginx/1.10.2 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.2)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 0
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
root@e8da5a56faec:/#
```

--

```
root@e8da5a56faec:/# passenger-memory-stats
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648
Version: 5.1.2
Date   : 2017-04-25 01:59:49 +0000
------------- Apache processes -------------
*** WARNING: The Apache executable cannot be found.
Please set the APXS2 environment variable to your 'apxs2' executable's filename, or set the HTTPD environment variable to your 'httpd' or 'apache2' executable's filename.


--------- Nginx processes ----------
PID   PPID  VMSize    Private  Name
------------------------------------
46    1     228.4 MB  0.7 MB   nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
49    46    228.4 MB  ?        nginx: worker process
1858  9     228.4 MB  3.5 MB   /usr/sbin/nginx
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 4.13 MB (?)


---- Passenger processes ----
PID  VMSize    Private  Name
-----------------------------
26   441.1 MB  1.2 MB   Passenger watchdog
29   654.1 MB  2.9 MB   Passenger core
35   449.3 MB  ?        Passenger ust-router
### Processes: 3
### Total private dirty RSS: 4.13 MB (?)
```

#### Nginx.conf (below)

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user  app;
#user nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include       /etc/nginx/passenger.conf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;


    index   index.html index.htm;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server_tokens off;
    server {
        listen  80 default_server;
        return  301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
    listen  443 ssl http2;
    server_name  yourserver.com;
        root         /home/app/public/;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_python /usr/bin/python3.5;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourserver.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourserver.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;

        location /static {
            alias /home/app/src_django/assets;
        }

}
}
```

#### Dockerfile (below)

```
FROM phusion/passenger-full

ENV NGINX_DIR=/etc/nginx
ENV APP=/home/app/webapp
ENV SCH_DIR=/your-scheduling

COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf $NGINX_DIR/

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Make SSL Cert directory
RUN mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourserver.com

# SSL Certs
COPY ./nginx/*.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/yourserver.com/

# Random Passenger Stuff
ADD ./nginx/env.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/
ADD ./nginx/secret_key.conf /etc/nginx/main.d/
ADD ./nginx/gzip_max.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/


# Get Code
COPY ./web $APP
COPY ./your-scheduling $SCH_DIR

# Install MySQL deps
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y libmysqlclient-dev

# Install Pip
RUN apt install -y python3-pip

# Run
RUN pip3 install -r $APP/requirements.txt
RUN python3.5 $APP/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN cd /your-scheduling && python3.5 /your-scheduling/setup.py install && cd -

# Things because Passenger says so
RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down
RUN rm -f /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD ./nginx/webapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf
# RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
app:
  restart: always
  build: ./
  links:
   - mysql:mysql
  environment:
   YOUR_KEY_FILE: /home/app/webapp/src_django/keyfile.txt
   DJANGO_SETTINGS_FILE: src_django.settings.settings
   YOUR_PROD: "True"
   PYTHONPATH: /home/app/webapp

mysql:
  restart: always
  image: mariadb:latest
  ports:
   - "3306"
  environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
   MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
   MYSQL_USER: db_user
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... Try adding:

```
ports:
  - 80:80
```

to the `app` service.

Comment: That did it. A few other things were off... but this got us over a big hurdle.